# odp.net db change notification

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, change-notification

Is there a way to get a notification when a certain field in a db table is changed ?
I'm using ODP.NET and Oracle 11g, on a .NET 4.0 app.

LATER EDIT :
So, from the answers i understand that it would be possible, so i've tried something.
This is how :

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();

        cmd.AddRowid = true;

        **OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);**

        cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnMyNotification);

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds, tablename);

        ultraGrid1.SetDataBinding(ds, tablename);
```

The problem is that it gets stuck at the marked like and after 60 seconds it throws an error :

```
The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x25f638 to COM context 0x25f7a8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question as it's answer will be different to the one I've provided and therefore will be useful to another user. One prompt though, are you only getting this when your debugger is connected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODP.Net does implement the Change notification that is specified by ADO.Net 2.0.

There's a brief description and a link to some sample code here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/win06odp-099708.html

Comment: I think it's important to note that your Oracle user needs to have the CHANGE NOTIFICATION privilege.

Comment: Also, the download does work, it just seems a little slow!  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/vsm-jun06-134538.zip