# Change OracleDependency timeout to unlimited

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using OracleDependency to receive notification when a DB changes. 
How do I change the notification timeout to an unlimited number of seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDependencyClass.htm), the way you specify the timeout depends upon the constructor you use when creating the `OracleDependency` object.

If you use `OracleDependency (OracleCommand cmd)`, then the constructor sets the `cmd.Notification` property to a new `OracleNotificationRequest` that it creates. After the constructor returns, you have set `cmd.Notification.Timeout` to 0.

If you use `OracleDependency (OracleCommand cmd, bool isNotifiedOnce, long timeout, bool isPersistent)`, then you specify a 0 for the `timeout` parameter.

If you use `OracleDependency ()`, then no OracleCommand is associated with the new object and so whatever you do, you would do after you call the new object's `AddCommandDependency(OracleCommand cmd)` method. This means you would set `cmd.Notification.Timeout` to 0.

The default value for the Timeout is 50,000 seconds so you have plenty of time to modify the Timeout before the registration expires.

Comment: This is the answer I want, thank you. And I still have another question, if I let it run 24/ 24 whether it affects the performance of the database or not? And how to cancel it when the application is shut down

Comment: Actually, it's two questions and they both deserve their own post because I saw no question about how to cancel and the [cancel post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307443/odp-net-db-change-notification) does *not* do justice to demonstrating a performance problem. I suspect the cancel question is pretty intuitive or obvious in the docs but answering questions in comments is bad for everyone. Doing it the right way means searching for answers yourself first and only after not finding, then you ask.